# Changing the & from citations in a multilanguage article

Tags: citing, languages

Title is self-explanatory, I think. More specifically, I'm writing in both brazilian portuguese and english and I want to change the & to "e" or "and" accordingly.

I'm currently using the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[brazil,english]{babel}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{filecontents}{ref.bib}
@article{cunha2007,
Author = {Cunha, Flavio and Heckman, James},
Title = {The Technology of Skill Formation},
Journal = {American Economic Review},
Volume = {97},
Number = {2},
Year = {2007},
Pages = {31-47},
}

\end{filecontents}

\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\&}{and}}
\addto\captionsbrazil{\renewcommand{\&}{e}}

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{brazil}
\begin{abstract}
Citation, conforme \citet{cunha2007}
\end{abstract}

\selectlanguage{english}
\begin{abstract}
Citation, according to \citet{cunha2007}
\end{abstract}

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{ref}
\end{document}
```

However, the `\addto\captionsenglish` overrides the `\addto\captionsbrazil`. I don't know if I did something wrong in the code or if this won't work and I'll need another way.

As an observation, I considered dropping natbib and running `\renewcommand{\BBAA}{}` and similars from apacite. This actually worked, but I have some "et al" citations I want to use, and I don't know how to do it without natbib, so I went back to it.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you considered dropping natbib I guess you can consider switching to Biblatex.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[brazil,english]{babel}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,natbib]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{ref.bib}

\begin{filecontents}{ref.bib}
@article{cunha2007,
Author = {Cunha, Flavio and Heckman, James},
Title = {The Technology of Skill Formation},
Journal = {American Economic Review},
Volume = {97},
Number = {2},
Year = {2007},
Pages = {31-47},
}

\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{brazil}
\begin{abstract}
Citation, conforme \citet{cunha2007}
\end{abstract}

\selectlanguage{english}
\begin{abstract}
Citation, according to \citet{cunha2007}
\end{abstract}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]